# Updating EnvironmentObject Variable by Assignment in Button

Tags: swiftui

I have a throwaway project I am using to try to familiarize myself with SwiftUI. Essentially, I have various types of apples, that I have made available through an `EnvironmentObject` variable. The project parallels the Landmarks tutorial that I have been through, but I am expanding on the use of objects such as steppers and buttons, etc.

I am currently attempting to have a button, when pressed, save the UUID of a certain variety of apple and send it back to the original view. It is not working, and I am not sure why. It seems like a problem of the `environmentObject` assignment not escaping the closure for the `action:`. Have have set print statements and Text views to display the values of the variables at certain points. While it seems to set the variable in the closure, it doesn't escape the closure and the variable is never really updated.

```
func scene(
  _ scene: UIScene,
  willConnectTo session: UISceneSession,
  options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions
) {
  if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView().environmentObject(UserData()))
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
  }
}

struct AppleData: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
  let id: UUID
  var appleType: String
  var numberOfBaskets: Int
  var numberOfApplesPerBasket: [Int]
  var fresh: Bool

  static let `default` = Self(id: UUID(uuidString: "71190FD1-C8E0-4A65-996E-9CE84D200FBA")!,
                              appleType: "appleType",
                              numberOfBaskets: 1,
                              numberOfApplesPerBasket: [0],
                              fresh: true)  // for purposes of automatic preview

  func image(forSize size: Int) -> Image {
    ImageStore.shared.image(name: appleType, size: size)
  }
}

let appleData: [AppleData] = load("apples.json")
var appleUUID: UUID?

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String, as type: T.Type = T.self) -> T {
  ... // Code Omitted For Brevity
}

final class UserData: ObservableObject {
  let willChange = PassthroughSubject<UserData, Never>()

  var apples = appleData {
    didSet {
      willChange.send(self)
    }
  }
  var appleId = appleUUID {
    didSet {
      willChange.send(self)
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView : View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var userData: UserData

  var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
    List {
      ForEach(appleData) { apple in
        NavigationLink(
          destination: AppleDetailHost(apple: apple).environmentObject(self.userData)
        ) {
          Text(verbatim: apple.appleType)
        }
      }
      Text("self.userData.appleId:  \(self.userData.appleId?.uuidString ?? "Nil")")
    }
    ... // Code Omitted For Brevity
  }
}

struct AppleDetail : View {
  @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
  @State private var basketIndex: Int = 0

  var apple: AppleData

  var totalApples: Int {
    apple.numberOfApplesPerBasket.reduce(0, +)
  }

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ... // Code Omitted For Brevity
    }

    Button(action: {
      print("self.userData.appleId: \(self.userData.appleId?.uuidString ?? "Nil")")
      self.userData.appleId = self.apple.id
      print("self.userData.appleId: \(self.userData.appleId?.uuidString ?? "Nil")")
    }) {
      Text("Use Apple")
    }
    Text("self.apple.id: \(self.apple.id.uuidString)")
    Text("self.userData.appleId: \(self.userData.appleId?.uuidString ?? "Nil")")
  }
  ... // Code Omitted For Brevity
}
```

The output of the print statements in the `Button` in `AppleDetail` is:

> self.userData.appleId: Nil
>   self.userData.appleId: 28EE7739-5E5A-4CA4-AFF5-7A6BFE025250

The `Text` view that shows `self.userData.appleId` in `ContentView` is always `Nil`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can access your @EnvironmentObject in any related subview so why should you pass it forward like this ? AppleDetailHost(apple: apple).environmentObject(self.userData). Also ForEach(appleData) should only work like ForEach(userData.appleData).

Comment: I should have said in the initial write up that I did that after it was failing to work. That was not my original code, and I did not reverse it before posting my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In beta 5, the `ObservableObject` no longer uses `willChange`. It uses `objectWillChange` instead. In addition, it also autosynthesizes the subject, so you do not have to write it yourself (although you could overwrite it if you want).

On top of that, there's a new property wrapper (`@Published`), that will make changes on a property to have the publisher emit. No need to manually call `.send()`, as it will be done automatically. So if in your code, you rewrite your `UserData` class like this, it will work fine:

```swift
final class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var apples = appleData
    @Published var appleId = appleUUID
}
```

Comment: We have a winner! Thank you for that! Obviously, I don't do this full time and it can be difficult to keep up with the changes. That fixed it right away. I also pulled out passing the EnvironmentObject from ContentView to the AppleDetail and it works as well.